# Given a row vector, how do I create an indicator matrix placing each value in its respective column location?

Tags: matlab, matrix

To give insight into the above title, I have a vector that is defined as so:

```
A = [1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4];
```

Given the above vector, how can I create this matrix in MATLAB?

```
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 3 3 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 4 4
```

Basically, for each unique value of `A`, there is one row associated to it.  With each row, the locations that are equal to the particular value of interest are placed in their respective columns.

What is the most efficient way to do this in MATLAB?

Comment: You should post any research you've done on this issue. Also, what you actually tried. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Consider taking a look at http://stackoverflow.com/tour to learn how SO works

Comment: I tried google but can't find no thing. I don't know which keyword I'll use to search

Comment: I agree that the OP should show what he/she has done, but the question seems well-posed to me.

Comment: I agree that the question shows no effort, but it's an interesting question and I have provided an answer as well.  BTW, you can't find this on Google because it's a matrix that has custom behaviour.  IIRC, there is no function in MATLAB that is built-in to do what you desire, so asking this question here is a good decision.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another approach is through [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) and [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html).  Assuming that `A` is a row vector, you would do the following:

```
un = unique(A.', 'stable');
out = bsxfun(@times, bsxfun(@eq, A, un), un);
```

`out` contains your desired result.  This code deserves some explanation.  The first line of code determines all unique entries in `A` stored in `un`, but provides them in `stable` order, or in the order in which they are encountered.  Not doing this would also **sort** the values too.  I figure that the case of values from 1 to 4 is a simplified example and you'd want to do this for numbers in any arbitrary order and them appearing anywhere in the vector as well.

The second line of code is actually quite elegant.  Let's start with the first `bsxfun` call that's nested inside:

```
bsxfun(@eq, A, un)
```

`bsxfun` is a very nice function that **broadcasts** over singleton dimensions.  What this means for our case is that `A` is a row vector and `un` is a column vector, and this would produce a **matrix** where we find the element-wise **equality** of two matrices - one matrix which duplicates row vectors of `A` for as many elements as we have in `un` and another matrix which duplicates column vectors for as many elements as there are in `A`.  The result of this is a matrix where each row tells you which locations in `A` matched a particular value in `un` starting from the beginning of `un` (first row) to the end of `un` (last row).  The last part of this is to take this equality matrix and do an element-wise multiplication with `un` using another `bsxfun` call so that `un` broadcasts itself again column-wise like what was done in `bsxfun(@eq, A, un)`.  The result would be to zero out the exact locations for each row that did not equal to the corresponding value in `un` that is represented and we thus have our result.

## Example

```
>> A = [1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4]

A =

  Columns 1 through 13

     1     1     1     1     1     2     2     2     3     3     3     4     4

  Column 14

     4
```

Calling the above code gives us:

```
>> out

out =

  Columns 1 through 13

     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     2     2     2     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     3     3     3     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     4     4

  Column 14

     0
     0
     0
     4
```

Comment: Very nice and complete answer, as usual ! I have the feeling that the OP is not very confident with Matlab so I woudn't have used `bsxfun`, which is, in my opinion, for more exprienced users.

Comment: @Ratbert - Merci :) Totally understand :)... however, it's never too late to learn!  FWIW, I only got good with `bsxfun` by starting to answer StackOverflow questions.  I didn't even know the function existed until I saw Divakar using it often.

Comment: @ILIKEANN - No problem at all.  Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`sparse`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) for that:

```
result = full(sparse(A, 1:numel(A), A));
```

---

Or initiallize the result matrix to zeros and then fill in `A` at the apporpriate positions using [`sub2ind`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html):

```
m = max(A);
n = numel(A);
result = zeros(m, n);
result(sub2ind([m n], A, 1:numel(A))) = A;
```

Comment: Heh!  Interesting approach with `sparse`.

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks! I've added another, based on `sub2ind`. But I like `sparse` better!

Comment: The `sub2ind` I like more because it makes you really think outside the box, but either of those methods are perfectly fine for me :)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your initial array is `A`:

```
for i=1:4
    B=A;
    B(B~=i) = 0;
    disp(B);
end
```

The tricky command in the middle replaces everything in `B` that is not equal to `i`.

Best,

Comment: Good canonical approach.  Probably just as fast as `bsxfun / unique`.