# How to generate a matrix of vector combinations with zeros for excluded elements?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, combinations, vectorization

I want to create a matrix from all combinations of elements of one vector that fulfill a condition

For example, I have this vector

```
a = [1 2 3 4 5]
```

and want to create a matrix like

```
a = [1 0 0 0 0;
     1 2 0 0 0;
     1 2 3 0 0;
     1 2 3 4 0;
     1 2 3 4 5;
     0 2 0 0 0;
     0 2 3 0 0;
     ........;]
```

and then get the rows that fulfill the condition I can use the command:

```
b = sum(a')' > value
```

but I don't know how to generate the matrix

Comment: Some hints here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30153890/given-a-row-vector-how-do-i-create-an-indicator-matrix-placing-each-value-in-it

Comment: should this work for an arbitrary condition or just the one you listed? What do you need the matrix for? There might be a better solution if you give more context.

Comment: Can you explain the pattern? Why does row `1 2 3 4 0` get skipped for example?

Comment: i thank for your answer, the main idea is that i have a vector with many max engine power and i want to know all the combination of engines that fulfill a power demand, and if i create a matrix with the engines powers combinations then then compare the sum of each vector with the power demand and then get only the combinations that meet the condition

Comment: sorry Dan the pattern `1 2 3 4 0` was skipped my mistake, i fix it thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate all possible binary combinations to determine the matrix you want:

```
a = [1 2 3];
n = size(a,2);

% generate bit combinations
c =(dec2bin(0:(2^n)-1)=='1');
% remove first line
c = c(2:end,:)
n_c = size(c,1);

a_rep = repmat(a,n_c,1);
result = c .* a_rep
```

Output:

```
c =

 0     0     1
 0     1     0
 0     1     1
 1     0     0
 1     0     1
 1     1     0
 1     1     1


result =

 0     0     3
 0     2     0
 0     2     3
 1     0     0
 1     0     3
 1     2     0
 1     2     3
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but this doesn't solve my problem, because the numbers move to other columns, and i want to prevent this

Comment: @efirvida why does the order of the numbers matter if you use a aggregate function like `sum`?

Comment: because after git the combination of engine that give me tho power demand need to optimize how many power use in each engine based on other rules, and if the order change i dont know engine is. for example i got 4 engine '[10 20 30 40]' and a demand of 25 mW any combination with the second engine (20 mW) meets the demand but how to use it i cant use 5 mW of the first engine (10 mW) and 20 of the second, or 10 and 15 of the same engines, and many others, if i maintain the order i can easily identify the engines by its position on the vector

Comment: @efirvida I updated my answer with a new method which preserves the order.

Comment: Nice approach! You could avoid `a_rep` with `result = bsxfun(@times, c, a);`